# point extraction in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

for an ellipse in binary image i applied this code

```
for(int j=0;j<poi.cols;j++)
{
    for(int i=0;i<poi.rows;i++)
    {
        if(poi.at<uchar>(j,i)==255 && n==0)
        { 
            lx=j;
            ly=i;
            n=1;
        }
    }
}

n=0;
for(int j=poi.cols;j>0;j--)
{
    for(int i=0;i<poi.rows;i++)
    {
        if(poi.at<uchar>(j,i)==255 && n==0)
        { 
            rx=j;
            ry=i;
            n=1;
        }
    }
}

n=lx;
int y;
cout << lx << "\t" << ly << "\t" << rx << "\t" << ry;
int d=(rx-lx)/5;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    n=n+d;
    y=0;
    for(int j=0;j<poi.rows;j++)
    {
        if(poi.at<uchar>(n,j)>=250 && y==0)
        {
            cout << "\n" << n << "\t" << j;
            y=1;
        }
    }
}
```

for finding  10 intermediate points (5 above & 5 below) along the edges. However, I'm not getting correct answer. At times it is not even detecting white pixels

Here's an example binary elipse

[image]

Comment: Indentation is needed.

Comment: Edit your code please. We can really do indenting for every new user!

Comment: what kind of indentation..sorry because im new to stackoverflow..

Comment: Your code is a good example for the benefit of having verbose variable names, and code comments of what the algorithm is trying to do. Just a friendly reminder, not everyone can do the effort to decode another person's code